# Zombie processes while using use_multiprocessing=True in Keras model.fit()

Tags: tensorflow, keras, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am encountering Zombie processes when training a Neural Network using Keras' `model.fit()` method. Due to the `<defunct>` processes, the training does not end and all the effected processes have to be killed with SIGKILL. Restarting the training script does not reproduce the same problem, and sometimes completes execution. The problem does not occur when multiprocessing is disabled: `model.fit(use_multiprocessing=False)`

Here is an output of the `ps aufx` command.

```
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
...
root      774690  0.1  0.0  79032 70048 ?        Ss   Mai23  17:16 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/tm legacy-worker run mlworker
root     1607844  0.0  0.0   2420   524 ?        SNs  Jun02   0:00  \_ /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/classifier-train
root     1607845 38.5  4.7 44686436 12505168 ?   SNl  Jun02 551:05      \_ /opt/venvs/classifier-training-repo/bin/python /usr/bin/classifier-train
root     1639337  0.0  3.7 43834076 10005208 ?   SN   Jun02   0:00          \_ /opt/venvs/classifier-training-repo/bin/python /usr/bin/classifier-train
root     1639339  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        ZN   Jun02   0:00          \_ [classifier-train] <defunct>
root     1639341  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        ZN   Jun02   0:00          \_ [classifier-train] <defunct>
root     1639343  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        ZN   Jun02   0:00          \_ [classifier-train] <defunct>
root     1639345  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        ZN   Jun02   0:00          \_ [classifier-train] <defunct>
root     1639347  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        ZN   Jun02   0:00          \_ [classifier-train] <defunct>
root     1639349  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        ZN   Jun02   0:00          \_ [classifier-train] <defunct>
```

Here are the relevant code snippets:

```
def get_keras_model():
    # some code here
    model = keras.models.Model(
        inputs=(input_layer_1, input_layer_2),
        outputs=prediction_layer,
    )
    model.compile(loss=..., optimizer=..., metrics=...)
    return model


def preprocess(data):
    # Some code here to convert strings values into numpy arrays of dtype=np.uint32
    return X, y


class DataSequence(keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, data, preprocess_func, keys, batch_size=4096):
        self.keys = keys
        self.data = data
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.preprocess_func = preprocess_func

    def __len__(self):
        # returns the number of batches
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.keys) / float(self.batch_size)))

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        keys = self.keys[idx * self.batch_size : (idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        return self.preprocess_func([self.data[key] for key in keys]


def train(model, data, preprocess):
    train_sequence = DataSequence(data, preprocess, list(data.keys()))

    history = model.fit(
        x=train_sequence,
        epochs=15,
        steps_per_epoch=len(train_sequence),
        verbose=2,
        workers=8,
        use_multiprocessing=True,
    )

    return model, history


data = {
    "key_1": {"name": "black", "y": 0},
    "key_2": {"name": "white", "y": 1},
    # upto 70M docs in this dictionary
}
model = get_keras_model()

model, history = train(model, data, preprocess)  # model training hangs
```

### Log Output:

Multiple `Caught signal 15. Terminating.` log messages are displayed, also when the training script finishes execution and does not encounter any Zombie processes. Same behavior is seen with `Exception in thread Thread-##` outputs; it occurs also when the model training is not effected by zombie processes and finishes execution normally.

```
Jun 09 14:16:22 mlworker tm[575915]: 2022-06-09 14:16:22,024 - MainThread - INFO - Start working on fold 1/5
Jun 09 14:16:22 mlworker tm[575915]: 2022-06-09 14:16:22.725522: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instruc>
Jun 09 14:16:22 mlworker tm[575915]: To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
Jun 09 14:16:23 mlworker tm[575915]: 2022-06-09 14:16:23.439638: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1532] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6882 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: Tesla P4, p>
Jun 09 14:16:23 mlworker tm[575915]: 2022-06-09 14:16:23,709 - MainThread - INFO - Fitting model ...
Jun 09 14:16:24 mlworker tm[575915]: Epoch 1/15
Jun 09 14:16:31 mlworker tm[575915]: 3/3 - 7s - loss: 6.9878 - acc: 1.0908e-04 - 7s/epoch - 2s/step
Jun 09 14:16:31 mlworker tm[575915]: Caught signal 15. Terminating.
Jun 09 14:16:31 mlworker tm[575915]: Caught signal 15. Terminating.
Jun 09 14:16:31 mlworker tm[575915]: Caught signal 15. Terminating.
Jun 09 14:16:31 mlworker tm[575915]: Caught signal 15. Terminating.
Jun 09 14:16:31 mlworker tm[575915]: Epoch 2/15
Jun 09 14:16:34 mlworker tm[575915]: Caught signal 15. Terminating.
Jun 09 14:16:34 mlworker tm[575915]: Caught signal 15. Terminating.
Jun 09 14:16:34 mlworker tm[575915]: Caught signal 15. Terminating.
Jun 09 14:16:34 mlworker tm[575915]: Caught signal 15. Terminating.
Jun 09 14:16:34 mlworker tm[575915]: Caught signal 15. Terminating.
Jun 09 14:16:34 mlworker tm[575915]: 3/3 - 3s - loss: 6.9392 - acc: 0.0055 - 3s/epoch - 1s/step
...
Jun 09 14:16:48 mlworker tm[575915]: Epoch 7/15
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]: Caught signal 15. Terminating.
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]: Caught signal 15. Terminating.
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]: Caught signal 15. Terminating.
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]: Caught signal 15. Terminating.
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]: Caught signal 15. Terminating.
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]: Exception in thread Thread-87:
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]:     self.run()
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]:     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]:   File "/opt/venvs/classifier-training-repo/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 759, in _run
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]:     with closing(self.executor_fn(_SHARED_SEQUENCES)) as executor:
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]:   File "/opt/venvs/classifier-training-repo/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 736, in pool_fn
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]:     pool = get_pool_class(True)(
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/context.py", line 119, in Pool
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]:     return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild,
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 212, in __init__
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]:     self._repopulate_pool()
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 303, in _repopulate_pool
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]:     return self._repopulate_pool_static(self._ctx, self.Process,
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 326, in _repopulate_pool_static
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]:     w.start()
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 121, in start
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]:     self._popen = self._Popen(self)
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/context.py", line 277, in _Popen
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]:     return Popen(process_obj)
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 19, in __init__
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]:     self._launch(process_obj)
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 73, in _launch
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]:     os._exit(code)
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/solute/click.py", line 727, in raiser
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]:     raise Termination(128 + signo)
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]: solute.click.Termination: 143
Jun 09 14:16:52 mlworker tm[575915]: 3/3 - 3s - loss: 5.7624 - acc: 0.0726 - 3s/epoch - 1s/step
Jun 09 14:16:51 mlworker tm[575915]: solute.click.Termination: 143
Jun 09 14:16:52 mlworker tm[575915]: 3/3 - 3s - loss: 5.7624 - acc: 0.0726 - 3s/epoch - 1s/step
Jun 09 14:16:52 mlworker tm[575915]: Caught signal 15. Terminating.
Jun 09 14:16:52 mlworker tm[575915]: Caught signal 15. Terminating.
Jun 09 14:16:52 mlworker tm[575915]: Caught signal 15. Terminating.
Jun 09 14:16:52 mlworker tm[575915]: Epoch 8/15
Jun 09 14:16:55 mlworker tm[575915]: Caught signal 15. Terminating.
Jun 09 14:16:55 mlworker tm[575915]: Caught signal 15. Terminating.
Jun 09 14:16:55 mlworker tm[575915]: Caught signal 15. Terminating.
Jun 09 14:16:55 mlworker tm[575915]: Caught signal 15. Terminating.
Jun 09 14:16:55 mlworker tm[575915]: Caught signal 15. Terminating.
Jun 09 14:16:55 mlworker tm[575915]: Caught signal 15. Terminating.
Jun 09 14:16:55 mlworker tm[575915]: 3/3 - 3s - loss: 5.6978 - acc: 0.1000 - 3s/epoch - 1s/step
...
Jun 09 14:17:02 mlworker tm[575915]: Epoch 11/15
Jun 09 14:17:05 mlworker tm[575915]: Caught signal 15. Terminating.
Jun 09 14:17:05 mlworker tm[575915]: 3/3 - 3s - loss: 5.5029 - acc: 0.0804 - 3s/epoch - 1s/step
Jun 09 14:17:06 mlworker tm[575915]: Caught signal 15. Terminating.
Jun 09 14:17:06 mlworker tm[575915]: Caught signal 15. Terminating.
Jun 09 14:17:06 mlworker tm[575915]: Caught signal 15. Terminating.
Jun 09 14:17:06 mlworker tm[575915]: Caught signal 15. Terminating.
Jun 09 14:17:06 mlworker tm[575915]: Caught signal 15. Terminating.
Jun 09 14:17:06 mlworker tm[575915]: Epoch 12/15
Jun 09 14:17:09 mlworker tm[575915]: Caught signal 15. Terminating.
Jun 09 14:17:09 mlworker tm[575915]: Caught signal 15. Terminating.
Jun 09 14:17:09 mlworker tm[575915]: Caught signal 15. Terminating.
```

No further log output was seen after the last message. The processes have to be killed with `sudo kill -SIGKILL` and model training has to be restarted again.

### System information:

I have encountered the same problem on different machines with different GPUs and different Python versions.

- OS Platform and Distribution: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye), Ubuntu
  20.04.4 LTS
- TensorFlow version: v2.9.0-18-gd8ce9f9c301 2.9.1 (Debian 11), v2.9.0-18-gd8ce9f9c301 2.9.1 (Ubuntu LTS)
- Python version: Python
  3.9.2 (Debian 11), Python 3.8.10 (Ubuntu LTS)
- GPU model and memory: Tesla T4 (16 GB) on Debian 11, Tesla P4 (8 GB) on another Debian 11 machine, GeForce GTX 1080 Ti (12 GB) on Ubuntu LTS

Answer (score 1):

We solved the problem with the following line at the start of the script:

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal.SIG_DFL)
```

**Explanation**:
We had a custom SIGTERM Handler in our script, which was interfering with the SIGTERMs sent to the Threads. This 1-line restores Python's default handler for SIGTERM and avoids running into unresponsive subprocesses.

There was no Bug in Tensorflow or Keras code :)